# Exclude fields from Gson serialization at runtime

Tags: gson

I've seen examples on SO of excluding fields from serialization at runtime.  I need to do that, but I'd like to have Gson handle serialization of all the fields not being excluded.

The complicating part is that I can't have Gson do the serialization first, then have a TypeAdapter modify the result.  I need to somehow do the exclusion first, then have what remains be serialized.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but a TypeAdapter is what is doing the serialization, it wouldn't be modifying the result since it itself is forming the result (JSON) as it goes, no?

Comment: @nickb I've seen an example on SO where default serialization was delegated by a TypeAdapter to the library, then the result was edited by the TypeAdapter to remove the excluded fields before returning the final result.

Comment: Interesting, do you have the link? It'd probably help better explain your question if you could provide the implementation you're describing along with an explanation of its shortcomings.

Comment: @nickb I figured something out.  But thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with some experimentation, and [this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13120355/369722), I was able to cobble together a way to conditionally exclude mocked fields.

The reason I'm going to all this trouble is that out-of-the-box Gson throws an exception when it encounters Spock-mocked fields.

For Spock, my check to determine if a field is mocked is to see if the class name of the value it references contains the substring `EnhancerByCGLib`.

Below, `ResizingArrayQueueOfStrings.arrayFactory` is the field that may, or may not, be mocked.

Thankfully, I can use a single `JsonSerializer` for all classes that need this sort of treatment.  Ideally, I wouldn't have to register the serializer for every class that might be mocked... but that's a battle for another day.

The resulting JSON, when the field is mocked and `ResizingArrayQueueOfStrings` is serialized, is

```
queue {
  "arrayFactory": "** mocked **",     
}
```

otherwise, it's

```
queue {
  "arrayFactory": {},
}
```

Hope this helps others with a similar need.

```
public class MockSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Object src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String className = src.getClass().getName();
        boolean isMocked = className.contains("EnhancerByCGLIB");
        if (isMocked) return new JsonPrimitive("** mocked **");
        else return gson.toJsonTree(src);
    }

}

public class ResizingArrayQueueOfStrings {

    private ArrayFactory arrayFactory;

    public String toString() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(ArrayFactory.class, new MockSerializer())
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();
        return gson.toJson(this);
    }

}
```