# GSON serialize null for a specific field affected during obfuscation

Tags: kotlin, gson, obfuscation

I want to serialize nulls for a specific field in GSON. I have looked at the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477267/gson-serialize-null-for-specific-class-or-field) as well as several others which fail when setting:

```
 minifyEnabled true
 shrinkResources true
```

I have been trying various (failed attempts) at modifying the answers given in the link, but I have not had any luck.

Given my object looks as follows:

```
data class EmojiType(
    @SerializeNull
    var value: String?
)
```

When I create a post request and pass null, I expect my object to look as follows:

```
{
   "value":null
}
```

However, as mentioned, when `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` are set to `true`, my object ends up looking like this:

```
{
   "a":null
}
```

How can I avoid this and retain the field name of `value`?

Comment: Where is `"a"` coming from?  I doubt that it's coming from GSON.

Comment: @CryptoFool I believe this is occurring due to the obfuscation process. When setting `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` to false, my "value" field stays intact, it's only when setting these values to true, that I get the "a". This is based on implementing the highest voted answer on the link I provided in my question.

Comment: Ah.  Ok.  I missed the obfuscation part of your question until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar issue with Gson, where specifying the SerializedName got it to work:

```
data class EmojiType(
    @SerializedName("value")
    var value: String?
)
```